# MySQL Performance issues with large amounts of data

Tags: c++, mysql, performance

I have a software project that I am working on at work that has been driving me crazy. Here's our problem: we have a series data contacts that need to be logged every second. It needs to include time, bearing (array of 360-1080 bytes), range, and a few other fields. Our system also needs the capability to store this data for up to 30 days. In practice, there can be up to 100 different contacts, so at a maximum, there can be anywhere from around 150,000,000 points to about 1,000,000,000 different points in 30 days.

I'm trying to think of the best method for storing all of this data and retrieving later on. My first thought was to use some RDBMS like MySQL. Being a embedded C/C++ programmer, I have very little experience working with MySQL with such large data sets. I've dabbled with it on small datasets, but nothing nearly as large. I generated the below schema for two tables that will store some of the data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `HEADER_TABLE` (
  `header_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `sensor` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `bytes` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`header_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `header_id_UNIQUE` (`header_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sensor_UNIQUE` (`sensor`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RAW_DATA_TABLE` (
  `internal_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `time_sec` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time_nsec` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `transverse` bit(1) NOT NULL default b'0',
  `data` varbinary(1080) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`internal_id`,`time_sec`,`time_nsec`),
  UNIQUE KEY `internal_id_UNIQUE` (`internal_id`),
  KEY `time` (`time_sec`)
  KEY `internal_id` (`internal_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rel_RASTER_TABLE` (
  `internal_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `raster_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time_sec` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time_nsec` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `header_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`internal_id`, `raster_id`,`time_sec`,`time_nsec`),
  KEY `raster_id` (`raster_id`),
  KEY `time` (`time_sec`),
  KEY `data` (`data_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The header table only contains 10 rows and is static. It just tells what sensor the raw data came from, and the number of bytes output by that type of sensor. The RAW_DATA_TABLE essentially stores the raw bearing data (an array of 360-1080 bytes, it represents up to three samples per degree). The rel_RASTER_TABLE holds meta data for the RAW_DATA_TABLE, there can be multiple contacts that refer to the same raw data row. The `data_id` found in rel_RASTER_TABLE points to the `internal_id` of some row in the RAW_DATA_TABLE, I did this to decrease the amount of writes needed.

Obviously, as you can probably tell, I'm having performance issues when reading and deleting from this database. An operator to our software can see real time data as it comes across and also go into reconstruction mode and overlay a data range from the past, the past week for example. Our backend logging server grabs the history rows and sends them to a display via a CORBA interface. While all of this is happening, I have a worker thread that deletes 1000 rows at a time for data greater than 30 days. This is there in case a session runs longer than 30 days, which can happen.

The system we currently have implemented works well for smaller sets of data, but not for large sets. Our select and delete statements can take upwards of 2 minutes to return results. This completely kills the performance of our real time consumer thread. I suspect we're not designing our schemas correctly, picking the wrong keys, not optimizing our SQL queries correctly, or some subset of each. Our writes don't see to be affected unless the other operations take too long to run.

Here is an example SQL Query we use to get history data:

```
SELECT 
  rel_RASTER_TABLE.time_sec, 
  rel_RASTER_TABLE.time_nsec, 
  RAW_DATA_TABLE.transverse, 
  HEADER_TABLE.bytes, 
  RAW_DATA_TABLE.data 
FROM 
  RASTER_DB.HEADER_TABLE, 
  RASTER_DB.RAW_DATA_TABLE, 
  RASTER_DB.rel_RASTER_TABLE 
WHERE 
  rel_RASTER_TABLE.raster_id = 2952704 AND 
  rel_RASTER_TABLE.time_sec >= 1315849228 AND 
  rel_RASTER_TABLE.time_sec <= 1315935628 AND 
  rel_RASTER_TABLE.data_id = RAW_DATA_TABLE.internal_id AND 
  rel_RASTER_TABLE.header_id = HEADER_TABLE.header_id;
```

I apologize in advance for this being such a long question, but I've tapped out other resources and this is my last resort. I figure I'd try to be as descriptive as possible Do you guys see of any way I can improve upon our design at first glance? Or, anyway we can optimize our select and delete statements for such large data sets? We're currently running RHEL as the OS and unfortunately can't change our hardware configuration on the server (4 GB RAM, Quad Core). We're using C/C++ and the MySQL API. ANY speed improvements would be EXTREMELY beneficial. If you need me to clarify anything, please let me know. Thanks!

EDIT: BTW, if you can't provide specific help, maybe you can link me to some excellent tutorials you've come across for optimizing SQL queries, schema design, or MySQL tuning?

Comment: does the data change in every second? are there pause periods where you could skip storing the data?

Comment: Running range queries over 100 million to a billion records in mysql is a painful thing if you are expecting instantaneous results. Are your "real time" requirements extremely stringent? If not there may be a possibility for you to offload some of this processing to batch jobs that generate aggregates for certain pre-selected ranges. Have you looked into partitioning the data at all. Is that a possibility?

Comment: Since you are new to Mysql. Are you familiar with Explain plans? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html

This article may help too:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/range-optimization.html

Oh yes, consider denormalizing the data as suggestd. Joins on tables with 100 million records is a killer.

Comment: Can't you use some sort of read only cache or will it be unacceptable for your users? If yes, you could look into something like http://infinidb.org/ for your cached data (it's way faster than a standard mysql db for retrieving infos from a lot of rows).

Comment: You were clear in specifying that you cannot change your hardware. IMHO, trying to handle this amount of data requires some serious processing power. If you cannot change the hardware config on the existing system, can you add more hardware (machines)? You could potentially look  into a distributed system like Hadoop for your needs if so.

Comment: The data doesn't necessarily change every second, but it's not deterministic. It changes based on whether or not a contact is moving in relationship to the sensor, essentially adds an element of randomness. I really like the de-normalizing idea for this problem. I assumed keeping everything in one table would be inefficient, I guess you know what they say when you assume... @Deep Kapadia, what has your experience been like with Query Optimizers? Do you recommend any specific one? I'll also take a look at hadoop, our current system is heavily distributed, but this particular module is not.

Comment: More than optimzers I was hoping you can look at the explain plan for your query and check if you were seeing full table scans or unused indexes and add the right kind of indexes. Query optimization is almost an art and requires patience. I would look at partitioning as I suggested earlier. @thekashyap outlined some good points. I have never used any optimizer tools just looked at explain plans and mucked around. Here are some good tips to start with: http://20bits.com/articles/10-tips-for-optimizing-mysql-queries-that-dont-suck/

Answer (score 4):

First thing you could try is de-normalizing the data. On a data set of that size, doing a join, even if you have indexes is going to require very intense computation.  Turn those three tables into 1 table.  Sure there will be duplicate data, but without joins it will be much easier to work with.  Second thing, see if you can get a machine with enough memory to fit the whole table in memory.   It doesn't cost much ($1000 or less) for a machine with 24GB of RAM.  I'm not sure if that will hold your entire data set, but it will help tremendously  Get an SSD as well.  For anything that isn't stored in memory, an SSD should help you access it with high speed.  And thirdly, look into other data storage technologies such as [BigTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable) that are designed to deal with very large data sets.

Comment: It would depend on the evaluation sequence of join and index lookup (where clause). Depending on teh usecase, it might actually be faster to "have 3 smaller tables and join some rows from each" instead of "have one huge table and do an index lookup".

Comment: This is an awesome idea, I always thought normalizing was the best strategy for storing data, I can definitely see that isn't necessarily the case for this particular problem.I'll have to give this a try...  Unfortunately, changing/upgrading the hardware is out of the question for us :(... Maybe in future builds this could be an option. Have you used BigTable before? Does it work well with heavy writing, reading, and deleting? This could also be an option for us.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of this is going to be trial and error.  Depending on the specifics of your use case.  Leaving the data normalized could help for certain queries, but if you end up having to do queries where you are joining millions of rows together, you had better be prepared to wait a while. The again, if you are only ever selecting very small parts of the data, and everything is indexed well, then I the three table method would work quite well.

Comment: @thekashyap How could I go about checking the evaluation sequence? Are there any good query analyzers out there you recommend?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never worked with MySQL. In Oracle you can see the use EXPLAIN and/or see very detailed info (e.g. hash-lookup, read xxx bytes,...) in OEM. Perhaps some MySQL expert can help out. ##edit## See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/execution-plan-information.html for MySQL.

Comment: PS: IMHO (as described in my post) doing these (query/index optimization, de/normalization) is secondary. Partitioning of table(s) is non-negotiable.

Answer (score 2):

I would say partitioning is an absolute must in a case like this:

- large amount of data
- new data coming in continuously
- implicit: old data getting deleted continuously.

Check out [this for mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html).

Looking at your select stmt (which filters on time), I'll say partition on the time column.

Of course you might wanna add a few indexes based on the frequent queries you want to use.

--edit--

I see that many have suggested indexes. My experiences have been that having an index on a table with really large num of rows either kills the performance (eventually) or requires lot of resources (CPU, memory,...) to keep the indexes up to date.
So although I also suggest addition of indexes, please note that it's absolutely useless unless you partition the table first.
Finally, follow symcbean's advise (optimize your indexes in number and keys) when you add indexes.

--edit end--

A quickie on partitioning if you're new to it.

- Usually a single table translates to a single data file. A partitioned table translates to one file per partition.
- Advantages

  - insertions are faster as physically it's inserted into a smaller file (partition).
  - deletion of large number of rows would usually translate to dropping a partition (much much much much cheaper than 'delete from xxx where time > 100 and time < 200');
  - queries with a where clause on the key by which the table is partitioned is much much faster.
  - Index building is faster.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with MySQL, but here are some a priori thoughts that jump to mind.

Is your select in a stored procedure?

The select's predicate is usually searched in the order its asked in.  If the data on the disk is reordered to match the primary key, then doing raster id first is fine.  You would be paying the cost of reordering on every insert though.  If the data is stored in time order on disk, you would probably want to search on `time_sec` before `raster_id`.

```
WHERE 
  rel_RASTER_TABLE.raster_id = 2952704 AND 
  rel_RASTER_TABLE.time_sec >= 1315849228 AND 
  rel_RASTER_TABLE.time_sec <= 1315935628 AND 
  rel_RASTER_TABLE.data_id = RAW_DATA_TABLE.internal_id AND 
  rel_RASTER_TABLE.header_id = HEADER_TABLE.header_id;
```

Your indexes don't follow the search predicates.

It will create indexes based on the keys, generally.

```
  PRIMARY KEY  (`internal_id`, `raster_id`,`time_sec`,`time_nsec`),
  KEY `raster_id` (`raster_id`),
  KEY `time` (`time_sec`),
  KEY `data` (`data_id`)
```

It may not be using the primary index because you aren't using internal_id.  You may want to set `internal_id` as the primary key and create a separate index based on your search parameters.  At least on `raster_id` and `time_sec`.

Are the joins too loose?

This may be my inexperience with MySQL, but I expect to see conditions on the joins.  Does using FROM here do a natural join?  I don't see any foreign keys specified, so I don't know how it would join these tables rationally.

```
FROM 
  RASTER_DB.HEADER_TABLE, 
  RASTER_DB.RAW_DATA_TABLE, 
  RASTER_DB.rel_RASTER_TABLE
```

Usually when developing something like this I would work with a smaller set and remove predicates to makes sure that each step meets what I expect.  If you accidentally cast a wide net up front, then narrow down later you may mask some inefficiencies.

Most query optimizers have a way to output *how* the optimized, make sure it meets your expectations.  One of the comments mention Explain plans, I assume that is what it is called.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what all the queries are its difficult to give specific advice, however looking at the single query you have provided, there are no indexes which are idealy suited to resolving this.

In fact the structure is a bit messy - if `internal_id` is an auto-increment value then it is unique - why add other stuff in the primary key? It looks as if a more sensible structure for rel_RASTER_TABLE would be:

```
PRIMARY KEY  (`internal_id`),
KEY (`raster_id`,`time_sec`,`time_nsec`),
```

And as for RAW_DATA_TABLE, it should be blindingly obvious that its indexes are far from optimal. And should probably be:

```
PRIMARY KEY  (`internal_id`,`time_sec`,`time_nsec`),
KEY `time` (`time_sec`, `time_nsec`)
```

Note that removing redundant indexes will speed up inserts/updates.
Capturing slow queries should help - and learn how to use 'explain' to see what indexes are redundant / needed.

You may also get a performance boost by tuning the mysql instance - particularly increasing the sort and join buffers - try running [mysqltuner](http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl)

Comment: hahaha thank you for the comment... Yeah, my table structures are quite sloppy. I was messing around with different things and happened to copy and paste the schema that seemed to work "best". My databasing skills are not the strongest, I definitely need to brush up on indexing, if you couldn't tell. I'll take a look at mysqltuner, too.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try to create a view with only the necessary info that needs to be selected between the different tables.

By the way, MySQL is not necessarily the most optimized database system for what you are trying to accomplish... Look into other solutions such Oracle, Microsoft SQL, PostgreSQL etc. Also, the performance will vary depending on the server being used.

Comment: You get what you "pay" for. :)

Comment: How would a view help here? It still runs the same select. Are you aware of a specific view algorithm that may work in this case? I am not challenging your statement. I'd like to understand your response better.

Comment: @thekashyap/Alerty Do you think another RDBMS would provide better results? It would benefit the OP if you could share some metrics.

Comment: @Deep Kapadia: From the MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-algorithms.html

Comment: @Alerty I still do not understand. How would a view help with the performance issue in this case?

Comment: "Do you think another RDBMS would provide better results?" Can't really say it would, but from support point of view yes. I mean with Oracle you can look at the "Oracle OEM" for optimizations. But if you know enough I'm sure you can do most things with MySQL as well. It's just easier with Oracle. Oracle had partitioning when others didn't, but now I see MySQL also has it.

Comment: "I still do not understand. How would a view help with the performance issue in this case? " If the view is materialized then it acts like a cache (not all queries goto DB) and helps the performance. Donno if MySQL supports materialized views. Oracle does.

Comment: No materialized views in MySQL out of the box. There are workarounds but some research seems to suggest that they are a pain to get working. Hence my question. MySQL only supports a temp table and a merge view, both require the SQL to be run every time someone selects from the view.

Comment: @Kashyap MyISAM is world-class fast and InnoDB is world-class tolerant, properly configured and with a well-tuned application layer. Also, support is not free for those at the Enterprise tier. There are things MySQL is extremely good at, but it does take specialized skills.